# Facebook OAuth redirect_uri not working

Tags: facebook-graph-api

To authorize a user on Facebook for my app, I am sending them to:

https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?client_id={0}&client_secret={‌​1}&redirect_uri={2}

The redirect_uri is set to http://mydomain.com/Page.aspx

Yet when it gets to the login and the user allows the application it redirects the page to:

http://mydomain.com/facebookredirect.axd

Which then just redirects again straight to the main page of the application instead of the /Page.aspx input as the redirect_uri.

Could anyone please tell me what is going on?

Thanks

**EDIT:**

Found out what was going on. I had incorrectly copied from an example.

So instead of https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?

I should have been using https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why do you use client_secret parametr? Delete it!

Comment: Thanks Anton. Late night programming lends itself to gaping security holes. :)